# Keep MVC.NET automatic routing, but add additional specific routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC.NET application that used the default routing engine to connect {controller}/{action}/{*pathInfo} and everything works fine.  I've added some WCF services to the project and need to setup specific routes to reach them.  The problem I'm running into is when I add the specific routes, the default automatic routing no longer functions.  How can I either use the default route handler with some overrides, or if that is not possible setup a generic route handler that automatically handles all existing Controllers/Actions and static resources?

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("services/rest/InvoiceService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(InvoiceService)));
            routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("services/soap/InvoiceService", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(InvoiceService)));
            routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("services/soap/LoginService", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(LoginService)));
            routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("services/rest/LoginService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(LoginService)));
            /**  WHAT GOES HERE? **/
            routes.MapHttpRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{*pathInfo}",
                new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });

        }

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            //RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); //OLD code that automatically handled routing
            RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes); //NEW code
        }
```

Comment: *The problem I'm running into is when I add the specific routes, the default automatic routing no longer functions* - the only reason this could be is if the additional routes you've added are matching requests that you don't intend them to. Without seeing the routes, that's the best answer you're going to get.

Comment: The {controller}/{action}/{*pathInfo} pattern catches /services/rest/InvoiceService if I make that first in the list.  If I arrange them as above, I get the WCF error message "Endpoint not found".  This is because it attempts to route "Dashboard/Index" to the WCF pipeline instead of the MVC pipeline.  /Dashboard/Index gets redirected to "http://localhost:51259/services/rest/InvoiceService?action=Index&controller=Dashboard

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - for posterity, you need to add a constraint clause to the MapRoute MVC handler that excludes the pattern you have for the WCF services.  Here is the final code block that worked.  The key part was the REGEX to exclude services as a valid controller name.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { controller = @"^(?!services)\w+$" }
        );
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("services/rest/InvoiceService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(InvoiceService)));
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("services/soap/InvoiceService", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(InvoiceService)));
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("services/soap/LoginService", new ServiceHostFactory(), typeof(LoginService)));
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("services/rest/LoginService", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(LoginService)));
    }
```

Comment: You gotta love when SO serves as a Rubber Duck